# Cannot upload apk on play store

Tags: android, google-play, release

I'm trying to upload an APK file on my Play Store account but I am getting this error message:

> You need to use a different package name because "foodlebee.com.foodlebee" is already used by one of your other applications.

I changed the name of the package going to: Refactor -> Rename -> Rename package.

As you can see in this image below:

[image]

I even created another key to sign the application as release mode. I generated another signed APK but I am still getting this error.

I tried to close and reopen Android Studio. I tried to rebuild my project, but nothing seems to work.

Edit 1:

It's showing the changed name in my Android Manifest:

[image]

Comment: you may want to rename the package name to a totally different one. Have you tried that?

Comment: check your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: 7geeky, thank for the reply. I'll try to do that and will let you know if it worked.

Comment: User1568088, I just posted a screenshot of my Android Manifest. It's showing the altered package name.

Comment: 7geeky, it didn't work. I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Make sure your ``Gradle - defaultConfig - applicationId`` not same in 2 project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, the package name is determine by the `applicationId` in `app/build.gradle` file. When you want to change the package name, you should change that field in gradle file.

see [the docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) for the details

Comment: So I went to: File > Project Structure > Modules/app > Flavours and changed the applicationID as you suggested. In addition to that I went to google-services.json and changed the package name as well in all occurrences to match the one I have in AndroidManifest and applicationid -> build gradle. It worked!